# How to prove that for some constant $c$, $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k^2} \rightarrow c$ $a.s.$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

On a certain fair die, four faces each have exactly one dot, one face has exactly two dots, and one face has exactly six dots. This die is rolled repeatedly. For each $n \geq 1$, let $X_n$ denote the number of dots that come up on the nth roll of this die.

Prove that for some constant $c$, $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k^2} \rightarrow c$ $a.s.$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

As per the given hint, I proved that $A_i$, $i \in I$ are events where $I$ is a nonempty finite or countable index set. Suppose $P(A_i)=1$ for each $i \in I$. Prove that $P(\cap_{i \in I} A_i)=1$.

I am not sure how this result will be helpful in solving the above question. I started the above question by using Chebyshev's inequality, but did not reach to any conclusion.

Can anyone suggest how can I solve this question?

Comment: I think some assumptions on the random variables are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k &\to \mathbb{E}(X) \\
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 &\to \mathbb{E}(X^2)
\end{align*}$$

Now use the continuous mapping theorem to conclude that
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2} \to \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}$$

Comment: By Slutsky's theorem L.H.S converges in distribution to a constant $\frac{E(X)}{E(X^2)}$. We know that convergence in a distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability. Is it true for a.s convergence?

Comment: @User124356 Let $A$ be the set of $\omega$ such that $\frac1n \sum X_k(\omega) \to \mathbb{E} X$. Let $B$ be the same for the denominator. Then for $\omega \in A \cap B$ the limit is $(\mathbb{E} X) / (\mathbb{E} X^2)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 1$. The "theorem" you need here is just for limits of real numbers.